# What's the difference between Pretest existing pooled connections and prestest new connections in websphere 6.1

Tags: hibernate, websphere, connection-pooling

What's the difference between Pretest existing pooled connections and prestest new connections in websphere 6.1..and which option is best one?

can we enable both options?

Answer (score 2):

You may enable both options simultaneously.

Pretesting existing pooled connections is much more useful because it deals with the common issue of stale connections within a pool of already opened connections. If the pretest fails, the connection is discarded and a new connection is established. "Active" connections are not pretested so the performance impact is limited. Otherwise, you would need to handle StaleConnectionExceptions as per:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rdat_stalconexp.html

Pretesting new connections is less useful but you can enable it if you'd like to get an "early warning system."